# Geometry - I am getting two different results when using two different scalar product properties

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inner-products

I am trying to solve a problem regarding the scalar product.
The problem has multiple choices, and I solved it in two different ways, and got different values. Both of the values were a choice, but only one of them is right, and I don't understand why.

Here is the problem:

Firstly, I have this image along with the following info:

[image]

- $[AB]$ is a diameter of the circumference of center $O$
- The radius value is 2
- The triangle $[AOP]$ is a right triangle

And then, I am asked the value of $ \vec {AP} \cdot \vec {AB} $.

Those are my two answers:
**Answer 1:**

$ \overline {AO} = 2 \\ \overline {OP} = 2 $

$ 
\overline {AP}^2 = \overline {AO}^2 + \overline {OP}^2 \\
\overline {AP}^2 = 2^2 + 2^2 \\
\overline {AP} = \sqrt {8}, \overline {AP} > 0  \\
\overline {AP} = 2 \sqrt 2
$

Since $O$ is the orthogonal projection from $P$ in $ \overline {AB} $,
$\vec {AP} \cdot \vec {AB} = \vec {AP} \times \vec {AO} = 2 \sqrt 2 \times 2 = 4 \sqrt 2 $

**Answer 2:**

$
\newcommand{\sininv}{\sin^{-1}}
\sin \alpha = \frac {\overline {OP}} {\overline {AP}} = \frac 2 {2 \sqrt 2} = \frac {\sqrt 2} 2 \\
\alpha = \sininv (\frac {\sqrt 2} 2) = 45º
$

$
\vec {AP} \cdot \vec {AB} = \overline {AP} \times \overline {AB} \times \cos 45º = \frac {8 \sqrt 2 \times \sqrt 2} 2 = 4 \times 2 = 8
$

The right answer is the second one. Why can't I use the first one to solve the problem? 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand this line $$\vec {AP} \cdot \vec {AB} = \vec {AP} \times \vec {AO} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the equation $\vec {AP} \cdot \vec {AB} = \vec {AP} \times \vec {AO}$, but your approach in answer 1 is just as good as in answer 2. Take a look at the following visual of vector projection (labeled corresponding to your image):
[image]

From this visual we see that the formula for the magnitude of the projection should be:
$$ \overline{AB} = 2\overline{AO} = 2\frac{\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{AO}}{\overline{AO}} = \frac{\vec{AP} \cdot (2\vec{AO})}{\overline{AO}} = \frac{\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{AB}}{\overline{AO}}$$
Implying that:
$$\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{AB} = \overline{AB} \times \overline{AO} = 4 \times 2 = 8$$